# "local variable referenced before assignment" but I think I need to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm receiving "local variable 'var_1_mon' referenced before assignment" and "local variable 'var_0_mon' referenced before assignment" when entering 0 or 1 for racer = str(input(">")). But to my knowledge I've already assigned their values, and if I assigned them after def game() it will reset my variables to those values after every turn.

I've tried putting the initial variable values after "def game()" and removing the Game loss and Victory conditions, but then choosing var_0 ended the program and var_1 didn't loop back to game().

```
import random
import time
def start():
        var_0_mon = 100
        var_1_mon = 100     
        def game():   
                var_0 = 0
                var_1 = 0
                racer = str(input(">"))
                if racer in ("0"):
                        player_mon = var_0_mon
                        enemy_mon = var_1_mon
                elif racer in ("1"):
                        player_mon = var_1_mon
                        enemy_mon = var_0_mon
                        while var_0 <= 100 or var_1 <= 100:
                                var_0 = var_0 + random.randint(1,2)
                                var_1 = var_1 + random.randint(0,3)
                                print ("Var 0:", var_0, "Var 1:", var_1)
                                if var_0 >= 100 or var_1 >= 100:
                                        break
                                if var_0 >= 100 and var_1 >= 100:
                                        print ("Tie!")
                                elif var_0 >= 100:
                                        var_0_mon = var_0_mon + 25
                                        var_1_mon = var_1_mon - 25
                                        print ("Var 0 Match Victory!")
                                elif var_1 >= 100:
                                        var_0_mon = var_0_mon - 25
                                        var_1_mon = var_1_mon + 25
                                        print ("Var 1 Match Victory!")
        game()
        if player_mon <= 0:
                print ("Game Loss")
        elif enemy_mon <= 0:
                print ("Game Victory!")
start()
```

I expected def start() to define the beginning of the game, so the player could choose a racer = str(input(">")) to choose between making their player_mon var_0_mon or var_1_mon. Then the game would proceed with var_0 or var_1 receiving random integers (1 - 2 and 0 - 3 respectively), upon which one would reach 100 before the other, or they would tie. Upon a tie, their the player_mon and enemy_mon would remain untouched, however upon the player winning, whichever of the two variable racers they've chosen (var_0 or var_1.) They would receive 25 to their player_mon and the enemy would lose 25 of their enemy_mon, and vice versa. game() would then return them to choose a racer, (var_0 or var_1). This would continue until one variable racer (var_0 or var_1) lost all of their money, if player_mon <= 0: or elif enemy_mon <= 0: printing "Game Loss" or "Game Victory" respectively, and then looping back to the very beginning of the program using start()

Comment: Why are you defining your `game` function inside of your `start` function?

Comment: You should learn about scope in Python.
https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html

Comment: Start is there so that the I can restart the game from the beginning including using the initial values.
Game is there so that I can restart the match, but not the entire game.

Comment: `player_mon` and `enemy_mon` will not be available outside `game`.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you assign to `var_1_mon` inside `game`, you create a *new* local variable that shadows the one defined inside `start`. You need to declare it non-local so that assignments affect `start`'s variable rather than create a new one.

```
def start():
    var_0_mon = 100
    var_1_mon = 100     
    def game():
        nonlocal var_0_mon, var_1_mon
        ...
```